# NFS directories created with wrong access

Tags: file-sharing, nfs

I created a shared NFS resource on a server to /share and mapped that on my client machine.

My problem is that even though I have defined this share on the server's /etc/exports as

```
/share xx.xx.xx.xx/24(rw,no_root_squash,async)
```

Files are created read-only. What have I done wrong?

And somehow NFS knows my ID on the server side even though it's different from the client's, will this work for anyone?

I'd also like to share the user's home directories set with the access users have defined, but this is not a priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your /proc/mounts or /etc/mtab; most likely, you're mounting it ro (as opposed to rw) on the client side.  Ah, wait, no!  Files are being *created* read-only?  That's a umask issue, either on the server or client ends.  Check shell umask and mount umask on the client end, and shell, daemon, mount, and exported umask on the server.  If you're creating files on the share with a program, also check the second argument to open(2)/creat(2).

As to the mapping, that's probably just an artifact.  Try "ls -n" to see the numeric uid and gid, which at the end of the day, is what NFS cares about.

Comment: Ah, thanks. It seems binding /home to /share/home works perfectly without any special configuration. As for the rest, it seems I can set the permissions from the client side as I wish (even use chown), so things work just fine!